# Prometheus query sum not working for different event

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have hystrix metrics for this command:

> hystrix_execution_total

that looks like this:

```
hystrix_execution_total{event="thread_pool_rejected", key="myapp"}
hystrix_execution_total{event="timeout", key="myapp"}
hystrix_execution_total{event="failure", key="myapp"}
hystrix_execution_total{event="success", key="myapp"}
```

All of them have some value.

I want to get the sum from timeout and failure but I have got a problem.

```
hystrix_execution_total{event="timeout", key="myapp"} + hystrix_execution_total{event="failure", key="myapp"}
```

When I execute this I have got No data.

But when I change the event to both of them to timeout or failure I have got the sum.

So why I cant get the sum of different event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Prometheus expects matching labels on both side of the expression.
You can do this instead:

```
hystrix_execution_total{event="timeout", key="myapp"} + ignoring(event) 
hystrix_execution_total{event="failure", key="myapp"}
```